# python string join syntax error

Tags: python, string, join

This question is about getting the string join method to work.

This code, from what I can see of python 3 documentation, should work:

```
str = "-";
seq = ("a", "b", "c"); # This is sequence of strings.
print str.join( seq );
```

But it's generating a syntax error for me:

```
  File "b.py", line 5
    print str.join( seq );
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It is not the `str.join()` call that caused the syntax error. Note: try not to use built-in names for variables, you are masking the `str` type.

Comment: If you didn't follow the link, python 3 `print` is a function, so requires parentheses around the argument list.  Bad idea to call a string `str`.  No need to end a statement with semi-colons in Python, unless you really enjoy typing semi-colons (believe me, the novelty will wear off).